# List emails if another table doesn't have it

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to return `mail@site6.com, mail@site4.com and mail@site5.com` only, by using SQL code?

List Emails that exist in Table_2 but not exist in Table_1. I can do it using PHP but must to do so by using SQL only.

```
Table_1
id | email
------------
1  | mail@site1.com
2  | mail@site2.com
3  | mail@site3.com

Table_2
id | email
------------
1 | mail@site1.com
2 | mail@site3.com
3 | mail@site6.com
4 | mail@site4.com
5 | mail@site5.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT IN`;

```
SELECT email 
FROM Table_2
WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM Table_1);
```

...or `LEFT JOIN`...

```
SELECT t2.email
FROM Table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1
  ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Actually not in is not null safe, so if table 1 is empty nothing will be returned

Comment: Thats wierd. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL.

Comment: @sagi I think it has to do with null values in rows, that is, the case when an email in Table_2 is null, not when there are no rows. Of course, that _may_ be something to consider if the data isn't clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
select email from Table_in
where email not in (select email from Table_2);
```

Comment: What is `Table_in`? And don't you have the logic backwards?